# Configure example.com for DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, bind

I have my bind server setup and when I do a nslookup it appears to be working as expected:
n1.mywebsite.com has an IP of 192.168.0.2

I have a zone added to my bind config for myswebsite.com with ip 192.168.0.3

Now, the question I have is, how do I configure my domain mywebsite.com? Do I use the default nameservers that my domain registrar offers and just use the NS records to point to ns1.nameserver.com? That to me would seem like overkill as I may as well just point the A record to the IP of the server instead. I have read about glue records but cannot find an option for it within my registrar ( who are Name.com ).

I have done some research but am having trouble understanding - so would appreciate an explanation along with any answer.

Thanks all.

Comment: I think at this point you'd be far safer just using the name servers at name.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The A record is not what you want to point to the Name server, unless you're defining an A record for your Bind server. What you want to do is point the nameserver (NS) records to your nameservers, so when someone queries mydomain.com, the Name.com nameservers will say "talk to dave's nameserver".

Then set up your zones on your local nameserver.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I have set mydomain.com to point to my registrars nameservers and have added an additional NS record to point ns1.mywebsite.com to my DNS IP address, but I receive an error saying "The Record Answer field is invalid"...

Comment: Ok, in your Name.com site, you should be able to chose something like 'use my own nameservers', you will need to put in two or more nameservers(for redundancy). When that is done, Name.com's nameservers will defer to yours when asked to resolve a name. You can then set up an A record(s), MX records, NS records, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Nick, please see my edited comment above - accidentally submitted whilst typing.

Comment: I don't know how much you know about DNS, and how much time you have to set it right, but this is a good opportunity for learning.. if you're under a tight schedule, it might be worth following lain's advice, and leaving the domain under the control of name.com until you're sure about the proper config. If not.. letting us know the domain name will allow people to see the exact configuration mistake.

Comment: hehe Nick - this is all one big learning curve :) Specifically went out of my way to do it this way as I have failed at doing it before and want to learn how to get it right. Are you saying that the fact it wont accept my NS record means I have a config issue? If I do a NSLOOKUP on the domain in question, I receive the correct response.  I also receive no errors when doing a dig on the domain name. Knowing that pointing my NS record to my DNS IP whilst still using my registrars nameservers should work - you have answered my qestion. I will investigate the issue wit my DNS config further.Thanks

Comment: Well, I wish you luck, the first thing you have to figure out is if you've completed your domain zone correctly, make sure you have all the pieces listed here: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/DNS-HOWTO-5.html NS records should point to a name, then you'll need to define an A record for that name further down, etc :)